# Update Multiple Views from Multiple Threads from Seperate External Classes

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I am working on a game project. I want to associate each view of my game to  its respective thread and then update the view according to the logic running in that thread.

To simplify, I am posting a sample:

This is Main Activity class, which will implement the UI:

```java
public class Main extends Activity{

    private View root;
    private boolean ready = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setContentView(R.layout.s_main);
        root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = root.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                ready = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void start(View view) {
        try {
            if (ready && !Threads.run) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    new AsyncTasks(this, R.id.txv1).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    new AsyncTasks(this, R.id.txv2).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                } else {
                    new AsyncTasks(this, R.id.txv1).execute();
                    new AsyncTasks(this, R.id.txv2).execute();
                }
            } else {
                Threads.run = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is AsyncTask extended class to update View:

```java
public class AsyncTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private TextView view;
    private boolean breakMove;
    private String updateError;

    public AsyncTasks(Activity activity, int viewId) {
        breakMove = false;
        updateError = null;
        view = activity.findViewById(viewId);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String message;
        Threads.run = true;
        try {
            while (!breakMove) {
                publishProgress();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            message = updateError != null ? updateError : "Thread Ends";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            message = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        try {
            breakMove = !Threads.run;
            if (view != null)
                view.setText(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 100));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            breakMove = true;
            ex.printStackTrace();
            updateError = ex.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Threads.run = false;
    }
}
```

This works good. But there are limitations:

- AsyncTask is recommended for short duration threads, not for Game or Long Running Thread projects.
- In latest android frameworks, only 5 AsyncTask threads can run simultaneously and rest will be in waiting queue. So it will not work if my project requires more than 5 views to update simultaneously.

What I have tried:

- Rest of other Thread implementations like Runnable, Handler, Service etc. don't allow to update views. Please keep in mind that my threads are coded in separate external files or classes.
- runOnUiThread is not recommended since it runs on UI thread so it will make Main thread busy all time and also it's output is noticeable after the thread which called it, ends.

I am looking for a simple clean solution like I have coded above to implement Updation of Multiple Views through Multiple Threads.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Simple and clean:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

    private View root;
    private Runs runs;
    private boolean ready = false;
    private final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setContentView(R.layout.s_main);
        runs = new Runs(this);
        root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        //
        ViewTreeObserver vto = root.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                ready = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRuns() {
        try {
            runs.run();
            Threads.run = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Alerts.alert(context, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void start(View view) {
        try {
            if (ready && !Threads.run) {
                startRuns();
            } else {
                Threads.pause = !Threads.pause;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Alerts.alert(context, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class Runs implements Runnable {

    private int count;
    private Handler handler;
    private TextView view1, view2;

    public Runs(Activity activity) {
        count = 0;
        handler = new Handler();
        view1 = activity.findViewById(R.id.txv1);
        view2 = activity.findViewById(R.id.txv2);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!Threads.pause) {
            update();
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, Threads.sleep);
    }

    private void update() {
        view1.setText(String.valueOf(count++));
        view2.setText(String.valueOf(Math.random() * 100));
    }


}
```